# Toggle Boolean Values in Multidimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, boolean

I am trying to get this method to be able to toggle between false and true for my 2 dimensional boolean array. Each value in the array corresponds to a square, but I need to toggle between the two whenever a certain square with coordinates row and column is pushed within the window. However, it is giving me an error for invalid operator == so I am not sure how else to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void clickSquare( int row, int column ) 
        {

             if (grid[row][column] == false)
             {
                 grid[row][column] == true;  
             }
             else
             {
                 grid[row][column] == false; 
             }
            return;  
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To *check if two values are equal*, use `==`.

To *assign a value to a variable (or array element)*, use `=`.

```
grid[row][column] == false;
```

should be

```
grid[row][column] = false;
```

and the same for `true`.

Also (but this is not related to your problem), note that your entire method can be replaced with

```
    public void clickSquare( int row, int column ) 
    {
         grid[row][column] = !grid[row][column];
    }
```

Comment: If I want to toggle all values can I use Arrays.setAll()? I tried `Arrays.setAll(boolArray, i -> !i);` but i is an int. `Arrays.setAll(boolArray, i -> false);` does work.

Answer (score 1):

The `grid[row][column]` is a `boolean` value, so inside the `if` condition you can just test the `grid[row][column]` to know if its `true` or `false`.

Inside your `if` block, to assign a value you must use the `=` operator.

To illustrate that, you can just use your code like this:

```
public void clickSquare( int row, int column ) 
        {

             if (!grid[row][column])
             {
                 grid[row][column] = true;  
             }
             else
             {
                 grid[row][column] = false; 
             }
            return;  
        }
```